# parsing string from json to datetime object

Tags: python, json, datetime, parsing

i'm trying to parse time strings from a json file, keep only the lines that can be parsed using the ISO datetime standard with strptime, take createdAt values that are already in ISO datetime standard and convert them back into strings (in UTC timezone) with strftime.

this is how my json data looks like, where createdAt for Fourth title is already in ISO datetime standard, but Fifth title should be removed as 12345678 is an invalid time object.

```
{"title_text": "Fourth title", "createdAt": "2020-10-17T02:56:51+07:00", "text": "Some post content", "author": "cereal"}
{"title_text": "Fifth title", "createdAt": "12345678", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"}
```

and these are two code snippets i've been working with.

```
datetime_formats = ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")

for time in range(len(data)):
    for format in datetime_formats:
        try:
            data[time]['createdAt'] = datetime.strptime(str(time), format).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
        except ValueError:
            pass 
        else:
            break
    else:
        data.remove(time)
```

^ this code snippet gives me a ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

```
def parse_createdAt_time(output_format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"):
    datetime_formats = ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
    
    for time in data[1]['createdAt']:
        for format in datetime_formats:
            try: 
                time = datetime.strptime(time, format).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
                return time.strftime(output_format)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                break
        else:
            data.remove(time)
```

^ i tried taking a slightly different approach with this code and tried to modularise it, but its not even parsing my json input. it just spits out my json data, untouched (so including the 12345678 entry above)

i'm also only allowed to use the datetime module, but i've spent too much time on this and still don't quite know what's wrong.

current code (inspo from @MrFuppes), which gives four "error"s and a TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable. it seems that all json time strings that use the iso datetime standard are parsing as a value error, and "fifth title" (which is an invalid time format) is giving me the type error.

```
def datetime_valid(data, output_format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"):
    final_json = []
    for line in data:
        for format in ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"):
            try: # see if json string is in iso datetime standard
                check_iso = datetime.strptime(str(line['createdAt']), format)
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
            else: # if string is in iso format, convert to utc and append to final_json array
                line = check_iso.astimezone(timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)
                final_json.append(line.strftime(output_format))
    return final_json
```

Comment: side note: don't modify an iterable while iterating over it (e.g. `data.remove(time)`) - this can lead to pretty confusing results ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if you have date/time in [isoformat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string, why don't you use isoformat methods? they're all part of the standard library...

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

l = [{"title_text": "Fourth title", "createdAt": "2020-10-17T02:56:51+07:00", "text": "Some post content", "author": "cereal"},
     {"title_text": "Fifth title", "createdAt": "12345678", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"}]

out = []
for d in l:
    try:
        dt = datetime.fromisoformat(d['createdAt'])
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        d['createdAt'] = dt.astimezone(timezone.utc).isoformat()
        out.append(d)
        
# out        
# [{'title_text': 'Fourth title',
#   'createdAt': '2020-10-16T19:56:51+00:00',
#   'text': 'Some post content',
#   'author': 'cereal'}]
```

Comment: this works when i copy and paste it into a jupyter cell, but not when i change l with my actual json file :/ i've made amendments to your code (e.g. still sticking to strptime because i don't want to lose the info in %H:%M:%S%Z) but i end up "error" (x4) and a TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable. i've edited my post to include this code + more detail as to what i think might be happening, would you be able to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to precisely understand your goal, but assuming you just want to filter your data list from entries with wrong date format for createdAt, you could use a function to build a new list with only valid entries :

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

raw_data = [
    {"title_text": "Fourth title", "createdAt": "2020-10-17T02:56:51+07:00", "text": "Some post content", "author": "cereal"},
    {"title_text": "Fifth title", "createdAt": "12345678", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"}
]

datetime_formats = ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
def filter_data(data):
    out = []
    for d in data:
        for date_format in datetime_formats:
            try:
                date = datetime.strptime(d['createdAt'], date_format)
                d['createdAt'] = date.strftime(datetime_formats[0])
                out.append(d)
                break
            except ValueError:
                pass 
    return out
```

yields

```
[{'title_text': 'Fourth title',
  'createdAt': '2020-10-17T02:56:51+0700',
  'text': 'Some post content',
  'author': 'cereal'}]
```